# How to set require if value is chosen in another multiple choice field in validation of laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5

I have a form like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="a">Option A</option>
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="b">Option B</option>
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="c">Option C</option>
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="d">Option D</option>
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="e">Option E</option>
<input type="checkbox" name="category[]" value="f">Option F</option>

<input type="text" name="description">
```

If option A is chosen, I want to make description required in backend validation in laravel 5. So I tried:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'description' => 'required_if:category,a',
    ]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
        return "error!"
}
```

However, the checking is not working. How should I set the validation rule to make it works?

Comment: You can try: `'description' => 'required_if:category[],a',`

Comment: Tried, but not working.

Comment: You should look at this too. I would help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43147584/laravel-validation-rules-if-value-exists-in-another-field-array

Answer (score 0):

First you need find index of checkbox with `value = 'a'`, in your example is `0` and it can be done by: `$index = array_search('a', $request->get('category'));`. And finally validation is:

```
[
    'description' => 'required_if:category.0,a',
]
```

Comment: Tried, it says "Validation rule required_if requires at least 2 parameters."

Comment: Well.... this works, but only for option A. If I change to 'required_if:category.1, b', and both option A&B are chosen, it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you put output of `dd($request->get('category'));`, when you have checked `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 0):

You may try as:

```
$validator = Validator::make($inputs, [
            'description' => 'required_if:category.0,a',
        ]);
```

If this doesn't solve your problem then you have to write a custom validator.

Comment: Well.... this works, but only for option A. If I change to 'required_if:category.1, b', and both option A&B are chosen, it doesn't work.